# UINavigationController animates on push but not when tapping back button

Tags: cocoa-touch, animation, ios6, uinavigationcontroller

I'm doing a storyboard segue when tapping a navigation bar button item, from view controller A to view controller B, and it works fine with a push animation. But when I tap the back button (no custom code) the previous view (A) just pops into place without the sliding animation. The same happens when I do a `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]`, i.e. there's no animation. I've made sure that I'm only popping it once.

This has been tested in the simulator as well as on a device.

I suspect it has something to do with what happens when view controller B is being unloaded or something similar, but I can't put my finger on it. I am handling an ABRecordRef property in B, but I have tried to be careful to call CFRetain and CFRelease in the setter when appropriate. I'm doing calls to outlets in various setters and getters but again have been careful to only do it if the view is loaded in case that would cause the view to reload after being unloaded. No success.

Finally did a log in B's `viewWillDisappear`, and `animated` is set to false. Why's that?

I don't know what to do next, my segue has the "push" style in the storyboard.

Comment: Any luck on this?  I am having the same issue with Xcode 6.1 and iOS8

Comment: I don't think I found the cause. The code doesn't exhibit the problem anymore that I know of. Post your code in a new question and maybe I'll get a flashback

Comment: I rebuild the UI in IB and added a super.viewDidAppear in my override of that function that I was missing. I have worked around it for now also.